# Change JAVA_OPTS for tomcat in AWS Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: amazon-web-services, configuration, spring-boot, tomcat8, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I deployed a beanstalk application (spring-boot) but it is crashing due to "GC overhead limit exceeded" exception. I checked that tomcat8 runs with Java options `-Xms256m -Xmx256m -XX:MaxPermSize=64m`.

I changed those by editing `/etc/sysconfig/tomcat8` to increase to `-Xmx1024m` only to realize that these changed are overwritten once you redploy the application.

Could someone help me make the configuration change permanent? I looked at the documentation [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/environment-configuration-methods-after.html) but it does not help. I don't see the options for JVM heap size in `Management Console`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Figured out how to do that using AWS Management Console. Following these steps:

1. Got o AWS Management Console: https://console.aws.amazon.com/console/home?region=us-east-1#
2. Click on `Elastic Beanstalk`. This would take you to the home page of your beanstalk applications.
3. Click on the application for which you want to configure Tomcat Java heap size. This should take you to the application's page (dashboard page by default).
4. On left hand side, you should see a menu. Click on `Configuration` in that menu.
5. Then click `Software Configuration`'s setting's gear icon.
6. In the following page, enter JVM min and max heap sizes in `Container Options`. -Xms corresponds to the min heap size and -Xmx corresponds to the max heap size.
7. Save configuration by clicking "Apply" at the bottom of the page.

Comment: Step#7 above is very important which is to click "Apply" button. I missed it and my JVM arg changes were not coming in effect.